# Install laravel to cloud9 and phpunit testing error

Tags: testing, phpunit, laravel-5, cloud9-ide

When I run program below,error has occured.

(i) In Cloud9, install laravel

(ii) copy "./app/Http/route.php" to "./app/Http/route_a.php"
add some lines in route_a.php

```
Route::get('/test/', function () {
    echo 'test';
});
```

(iii) I edit "./tests/ExampleTest.php".

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->editRoute();

        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
        $this->visit('https://laravel-cloned-test1-dog-ears.c9users.io/test/');
    }

    private function editRoute(){
        $this->files = new Filesystem;
        $this->files->move( './app/Http/routes.php', './app/Http/routes_b.php');
        $this->files->move( './app/Http/routes_a.php', './app/Http/routes.php');
        Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
        Artisan::call('cache:clear');        
    }
}
```

(iv) run phpunit

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

And error has occured below.

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
A request to [http://localhost/test] failed. Received status code [404].
```

After error, commentout "editRoute()",
and run phpunit again, then there is no error.

Please Someone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to browse the Laravel installed page at all?  Not sure how you did install but you need to make some slight apache tweaks detailed here https://community.c9.io/t/getting-started-with-laravel/1608

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I can brouse page with no trouble.
but,test has errors.
I install laravel with same manner written in your reference page.

Comment: This problem is solved in other QandA Site. Solution is to run "$this->editRoute();" in setUp function. then run "parent::setUp();".Change route and setup laravel. Important factor is order. That's all. Thank you.